# Turning an exact string into a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, flot

I have an external API creating a string which I would like to use with a Flot graph.
Here is what the API returns:
`[[0, 240.5],[1, 238.77],[2, 240.46],[30, 243.99]]`
However, using `$.get` in JQuery returns it as a string, whereas I would like it as a Javascript array exactly the same.
Is there any way for me to change the string into an array exactly as shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the `JSON` object.

It provides a method to parse JSON strings to JSON objects:

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(getData);
```

From there, the variable we defined `parsedData` can be used as an array.

```
parsedData[0][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `$.getJSON`

```
$.getJSON("/path/to/server")
.then(function(data) {
  console.log($.isArray(data), data);
});
```

---

```js
$.getJSON("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/" 
          + "guest271314/23e61e522a14d45a35e1/raw/" 
          + "62775b7420f8df6b3d83244270d26495e40a1e9d/a.json")
.then(function(data) {
    console.log($.isArray(data), data)
}, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse`:

```
$.get('url', function(data) {
  var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
  // now parsed will be a 2D array
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Parse it.

```
var yourvar = "[[0, 240.5],[1, 238.77],[2, 240.46],[30, 243.99]]"; // or just "data" variable in your case (using $.get)
var array = JSON.parse(yourvar);
```

Comment: Anyone downvoting cares to explain?